# Data Frame in Panda with Time series data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, histogram

I just started learning pandas. I came across this;

```
d = date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
s = Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
```

I have understood what is the above data means and I tried with IPython:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
import time
r = date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
r
len(r)
[r[i] for i in range(len(r))]
s = Series(randn(len(r)), index=r)
s
s.plot()
df_new = DataFrame(data = s, columns=['Random Number Generated'])
```

Is it correct way of creating a data frame?

The Next step given is to : Return a series where the absolute difference between a number and the next number in the series is less than 0.5

Do I need to find the difference between each random number generated and store only the sets where the abs diff is < 0.5 ? Can someone explain how can I do that in pandas?

Also I tried to plot the series as histogram with;

```
 df_new.diff().hist()
```

The graph display the x as Random number with Y axis 0 to 18 (which I don't understand). Can some one explain this to me as well?

Comment: Given the date_range, r, that data frame can be created as: `DataFrame(index=r, data=randn(len(r)), columns=['Random Number Generated'])`.

Comment: whats is the difference between the way I created and the way u suggested. Can you explain me pls Im new to Pandas.

Comment: I was just pointing out that creating the Series, s, isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks :) Dithal. Can you please clarify me if you have any idea on the abs different thing

Comment: I don't really understand that part of you question.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me the histogram pic I got. Why it shows as 0 to 18 in Y axis

Comment: The y-axis values of 0 to 18 are the bin counts. The bins are on the x-axis. To see what's going on, try `hist(bins=1)`, you should get 72 on the y-axis, the length of the data.

Answer (score 1):

To give you some pointers in addition to @Dthal's comments:

```
r = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
```

As commented by @Dthal, you can simplify the creation of your `DataFrame` randomly sampled from the normal distribution like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=r, data=randn(len(r)), columns=['Random Number Generated'])
```

To show only `values` that differ by less than `0.5` from the preceding value:

```
diff = df.diff()
diff[abs(diff['Random Number Generated']) < 0.5]

                     Random Number Generated
2011-01-01 02:00:00                 0.061821
2011-01-01 05:00:00                 0.463712
2011-01-01 09:00:00                -0.402802
2011-01-01 11:00:00                -0.000434
2011-01-01 22:00:00                 0.295019
2011-01-02 03:00:00                 0.215095
2011-01-02 05:00:00                 0.424368
2011-01-02 08:00:00                -0.452416
2011-01-02 09:00:00                -0.474999
2011-01-02 11:00:00                 0.385204
2011-01-02 12:00:00                -0.248396
2011-01-02 14:00:00                 0.081890
2011-01-02 17:00:00                 0.421897
2011-01-02 18:00:00                 0.104898
2011-01-03 05:00:00                -0.071969
2011-01-03 15:00:00                 0.101156
2011-01-03 18:00:00                -0.175296
2011-01-03 20:00:00                -0.371812
```

Can simplify using `.dropna()` to get rid of the missing values.

The `pandas.Series.hist()` [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.hist.html) inform that the default number of `bins` is `10`, so that's number of `bars` you should expect and so it turns out in this case roughly symmetric around zero ranging roughly `[-4, +4]`.

> Series.hist(by=None, ax=None, grid=True, xlabelsize=None, xrot=None, ylabelsize=None, yrot=None, figsize=None, bins=10, **kwds)
>       diff.hist()

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation stefen :) I tried the same but when I tried to create the bar : df_new = diff[abs(diff['Random Number Generated']) < 0.5] , df_new.diff().hist(bins =10). I am getting different graph

Comment: Am I missing something ?

Comment: Do I need to specify the axis explicitly ?

Comment: I dont have the symmetry like your graph What should I do ?

Comment: That's because you are reducing the number of valid observations to around 20, so with `bins=10`, that is 2 values per bin on average, you can get all sorts of shapes. My chart above was for the 72 values, ie the full series, before dropping the values with `abs(diff<0.5)`.

Comment: Just let me know if this answered your question or if you need anything else.